# How to have a scrollable table which takes the height from it's parent (HTML + Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like to make a table vertically scroll using the standard overflow: auto, but not have to set a height on the table's container.

Bootstrap has a built in class table-responsive to handle horizontal scrolling, but I can't work out how to make vertical scrolling without a max height directly on the table's container.

Here's the basic HTML and BS:

```
    <div class="card card-bordered m-3 w-50" style="height: 400px">
      <div class="card-body px-3 pt-2 pb-0">
        <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: auto">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-sm mb-0">
            <thead>
```

and here is a codepen of the full card: https://codepen.io/Daggett/pen/wvvJxpp

As you can see if you add more tr rows to the table, there is no scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w-50 border m-5 d-flex flex-column" style="height: 400px; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0">


  <!-- Header takes height of content, height is fixed by flex-shrink and flex-grow -->
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3" style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0">
    <h4 class="mb-0">Title</h4>
  </div>


  <!-- Can add more divs with height taken from their content, fixed with flex -->
  <div class="mb-2 px-3 d-flex align-items-center" style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input">
  </div>


  <!-- Now set body that has the variable size, using flex-grow-1 to fill the space  -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
    <!-- Set overflow  -->
    <div class="mx-3" style="overflow: auto">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. Consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed.
        Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Euismod
        lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla. Euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin.
        Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id. Tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. Diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum. Duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit.
        Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer
        quis. Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum. Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque
        id nibh tortor. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Enim blandit volutpat
        maecenas volutpat. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Tempor id eu nisl nunc. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Duis at tellus at urna. Leo integer malesuada
        nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Ipsum faucibus vitae
        aliquet nec. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet. Sed velit dignissim sodales
        ut eu sem. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. Cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Vel orci porta non pulvinar.
        Id diam vel quam elementum. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Eget nullam non nisi est sit. Id diam vel quam elementum
        pulvinar. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl. Urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Velit egestas dui id ornare. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque.
        Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. Feugiat in ante metus dictum. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam.
        Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Sollicitudin aliquam
        ultrices sagittis orci a. Aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Egestas dui id ornare arcu odio. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Scelerisque varius
        morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. Arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh
        cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu. Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet. Vel orci porta non
        pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Scelerisque felis imperdiet
        proin fermentum leo vel orci.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="px-3 py-2 border-top" style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0">
    <p class="mb-0">Footer</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

It's necessary to add d-flex flex-grow one to the content container, then having the overflow:auto on the content.

To fix the height of the non variable parts, flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0 is necessary to stop resizing.

Answer (score 2):

I have moved the `height:400px` to 'card-body' and applied `height:100%` to `table-responsive`. This is so the header can stay it's fixed height and the table can expand to the `400px` height of the parent.

https://codepen.io/anijack/pen/YzzZOWE

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-bordered m-3 w-50">
  <!-- Can use w-25, w-50, w-75, w-100 to set width - use max-height CSS to set the height of the card -->

  <div class="card-header px-3 pt-2 pb-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="height: 44px">
    <!-- Fix the height of the header -->
    <h4 class="mb-0">Visualize data</h4>

  

  </div>

  <div class="card-body px-3 pt-2 pb-0" style="height: 400px">
    

    <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: auto;height:100%;">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-sm mb-0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-nowrap" scope="col">
              Tenor
              <button class="btn btn-flat-primary btn-sm ml-2">
                <i class="icon">add</i>
              </button>
            </th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">1Y</th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">2Y</th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">3Y</th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">5Y</th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">8Y</th>
            <th class="text-right px-3" scope="col">10Y</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              01 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              02 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              03 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-secondary text-nowrap" scope="row">
              04 Mar 19
            </th>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
            <td class="text-right px-3">00.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="card-footer px-3 py-0 border-top d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="min-height: 48px">

    <button class="btn btn-link px-1">Clear</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution - I was hoping to avoid having to put a height on the body too but perhaps this is the only way

Comment: A percentage or fixed height needs to be set for an element to scroll with overflow, otherwise the browser doesn't know when the scrolling should begin. I don't think there is a way around that.